# Let $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $f$ be a function defined on a deleted neighborhood of $x_0$

Tags: calculus

T/F - Let $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $f$ be a function defined on a deleted neighborhood of $x_0$. If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ then the limit $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0}-h)}{2h}$ exists.

To me it looks like a slight veriation of the limit formula that is still true. But I am just stuck after hours of trying. I need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*:
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0 - h)}{2h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{[f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)] - [f(x_0 - h) - f(x_0)]}{2h}$$

Comment: simply and elegant, thanks